# Exception when running Flink program from Eclipe IDE

Tags: apache-flink

I'm having the following exception when running Flink program from Eclipse:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Insufficient number of network buffers: required 8, but only 4 available. The total number of network buffers is currently set to 2048. You can increase this number by setting the configuration key 'taskmanager.network.numberOfBuffers'.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBufferPool.createBufferPool(NetworkBufferPool.java:196)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.NetworkEnvironment.registerTask(NetworkEnvironment.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:577)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The documentation (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/config.html#configuring-the-network-buffers) says number of network buffers can be changed via `conf/flink-conf.yaml`. But it's not clear how to change it when running a program from IDE.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating execution environment with Configuration object

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
int defaultLocalParallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
cfg.setString("taskmanager.network.numberOfBuffers", "3000");
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(defaultLocalParallelism, cfg);
```